# Two projects in a solution that use different default paths

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have two projects in my solution, `ChatProject` and `ChatProjectTest`.

`ChatProjectTest` has a single class file that has many methods that test methods in `ChatProject`.

My problem is that `ChatProject` uses some files, like `data.bin` and `log.txt`, that are stored in the `.exe` folder (that is `ChatProject\bin\Debug\ChatProject.exe`). I want `ChatProjectTest` to use the same files, and not go ahead and create or load new files in its own `.exe` folder (`ChatProjectTest\bin\Debug\ChatProject.exe`), like it does currently.

To be clear, the file paths are stored in constant variables in `ChatProject` like this:

`private static string DATABASE_NAME = "data.bin";`

I didn't hardcode their paths.

Comment: It's not clear to me if you want this to work at run time or compile/build time? For compile time, you could add the file as a `link` to the ChatProjectTest

Answer (score 4):

One solution can be configuring your projects to put all the output files into the same the same `bin/` directory under your solution root (instead of two separate `bin/` folders).
To do this, go to the "Build" tab under project settings and set "Output path" to

`$(SolutionDir)Bin\$(Configuration)\`

Repeat this for both of your projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a path to a file it looks in the current directory for them.
To use the same ones, you either have to specify some sort of relative path from the Test Output, or build the tests into the same folder as the Project.

Answer (score -1):

You may allow the target file path to be injected e. g. via an optional constructor parameter:

```
public class SampleClass
{
    private readonly string OutputDirectory;

    public SampleClass(string outputDirectory = ".")
    {
        OutputDirectory = outputDirectory;
    }

    public void WriteData(string data)
    {
        File.AppendAllText($"{OutputDirectory}\\data.bin", data);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class SampleClassTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void WriteDataTest()
    {
        var sut = new SampleClass("..\\..\\..\\ChatProject\\bin\\Debug");
        sut.WriteData("data");
    }
}
```